# JQuery Onload refresh iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a page which contains an iframe.

My problem is that I sometimes need to modify the iframe's page but the changes are not showing on the main page unless I go to that frame and reload it manually.

Is there a way to refresh the iframe when the page loads or similar way to sort this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#your_iframe_id').attr( 'src', function ( i, val ) { return val; });
});
```

Did you mean like that

Answer (score 0):

Re-setting the `src` attribute of the iframe is sufficient to cause it to reload. For example:

```
$(function() {
  $('#idOfIFrame').attr('src', 'http://yourDomain.tld/yourPage');
});
```

Will cause the iframe to load `http://yourDomain.tld/yourPage`.

Alternatively, if the iframe src is on the same domain as the outer page, you can trigger a refresh by the following:

```
document.getElementById('idOfIFrame').contentDocument.location.reload(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing the iframe is on the same domain as the parent page, the following JavaScript will perform a reload:

```
document.getElementById('iframeID').contentDocument.location.reload(true);
```

You can use that whenever you need to refresh it.